# getting input box value undefined in alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get input field value. Only based on class and id name.
I am getting undefined in alert box.
Not getting any value which i have entered in input box.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">
        <div class="input-text">
            <div class="input-append">
                <input id="textData" class="input-xxlarge" type="text" name="inputName" />
                <button id="pressme" class="btn btn-success btn-large" type="button">Convert</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
 $('#pressme').on({
     'click': function () {
         var data = $(".tab-pane active #textData").val();
         alert(data);

     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect as the `div` has both classes, so you need to join them together like this:

```
var data = $(".tab-pane.active #textData").val();
```

Note that `id` selectors should be unique, so in effect the class selector is redundant anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`.tab-pane active` looks for an `<active>` element inside of an element with a class of `tab-pane`. The correct selector for an element with those two classes would be `.tab-pane.active`., but since your element has an id, just select it using an id selector:

```
$("#textData").val();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the selector as your text box id enough

```
var data = $("#textData").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be like

```
$('#pressme').on({
     'click': function () {
         var data = $(".tab-pane.active #textData").val();
         alert(data);
     }
});
```

Makesure that you have enclosed it on `DOM ready`

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS:

```
 $('#pressme').on('click',function () {
         var data = $("#textData").val();
         alert(data);

     });
```